# BardAPI (unofficial) doesn't work with upgrade

Tags: google-generativeai

I used the unofficial api (BardAPi at https://github.com/dsdanielpark/Bard-API) through the cookies on the bard site.
Now with the upgrade from bard to gemini from the browser it no longer works for me.

How can I solve it? is there a method besides Vertex AI?

the gemini api doesn't work in europe, I don't have a VPN available and I can't create a vertex ai account because I don't have the correct payment method in a short time

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-vertex Gemini API: https://ai.google.dev/

You can use the UI through AI Studio: https://aistudio.google.com/

You don't need to set up payment like Vertex, and [there's a free tier](https://ai.google.dev/pricing).

Comment: In europe non-vertex Gemini API and AI Studio doesn't allowed..